# how to provide trust (CA) certificate to ldapmodify on RedHat

Tags: ssl, ldap, redhat

I'm trying to use LDAP client (ldapmodify) on Redhat Linux to manipulate the contents of Active Directory which obliges me to use LDAPS. The ldapmodify quits with "Can't contact LDAP server" and the additional info is "Peer certificate issuer is not recognized".

Can I specify a trust store to it? If so, how? And what format should it be?
Or, perhaps, I can add the CA certificate to the default store? How can I find it?
Thanks.